# Negative Regex pattern matching in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have the two below lines as output

```
   1   ID_1    INSV  enabled   Activated   12.345.67.89
   2   ID_2    SYSB  Disabled  Activated    12.345.67.89
```

I want to match the lines that should NOT have SYSB but it should have Activated. I am writing the below regex

```
ID_\d+\s+(?!SYSB)\s+\w+\s+Activated
```

It ignores the SYSB line, but its not capturing INSV line too. How to solve this regex?

Comment: You can use `^(?!.* SYSB ).* Activated\b`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just check each line and use the `in`, `and`, `not` operators instead?

Comment: A compiled regex should perform better depending on the number of rows.

Comment: While @anubhava answer works, I wanted to answer your question directly. Your regex is not matching cos it doesn't have anything that matches the word in place of SYSB. The corrected version could be: `ID_\d+\s+(?!SYSB)\w*\s+\w+\s+Activated` adding that \w* to match `INSV` in your example case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use negative lookahead like this:

```
^(?!.* SYSB ).* Activated\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Y5Igv/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.* SYSB )`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if `" SYSB "` is present anywhere in the line
- `.* Activated\b`: Match word `Activated` anywhere in the line after a space. `\b` is for word boundary.